# How to detect when AVPlayer starts/stops playing in swift

Tags: swift, ios9, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayer inside a scrollView and for some reason when the AVPlayer plays the scrollview jumps to the top causing the video to not be visible on the screen as the video is torward the bottom of the scrollView. So inorder to stop the scrollView from jumping I want to disable and enable scrolling when the user starts/stops the video. Not sure if that will solve my problem but I'm hoping someone knows the right way to add an observer or notification for the player so I can test it out.

This is the code I have inside my ViewController that contains some static text and the AVPlayer. 
**Code Below:**

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("carbon_video", ofType:"mp4")

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    var player = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    player.player = avPlayer
    self.addChildViewController(player)
    player.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    p.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    avPlayer.play()
    paused = false
    // Disable scrolling
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    avPlayer.pause()
    paused = true
// Enable scrolling
}
```